# Call Trackingscript with JMeter and JavaScript?

Tags: selenium, jmeter, tracking

is it possible to call a tracking script (e.g Google Analytics) 100x or more often with JMeter and Javascript?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [JMeter Project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So I don't think you will be able to use JMeter standalone to mimic hundreds of tracking events (and I also don't think it's legal)

However if you're 100% sure that you're doing the right thing you can consider implementing JMeter integration with Selenium via [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler), just remember that real browsers are very resource intensive therefore you will need something like 100 CPU Cores and 200 GB of RAM for 100 browser instances so most probably you will have to go for [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Dmitri T  - Do you know an recommended way how I will be able to run mutliple browsers in parallel?